# Python Requests payload format

Tags: python

I am working on a POST request using requests library.

My post requests is working fine if I am using carriage returns in my payload, such as this:

```
payload = "{\r\n        \"name\": \r\n        {\r\n            \"@action\": \"login\",\r\n            \"@appname\": \"app\",\r\n            \"@class\": \"login\",\r\n            \"@nocookie\": 1,\r\n            \"@code\": \"101\",\r\n            \"@psw\": \"12345\",\r\n            \"@relogin\": \"0\",\r\n            \"@username\": \"user123\"\r\n        }\r\n}\r\n"
```

But if I format it to make the payload look pretty the request is not working:

```
payload = { 
    'name': 
        { 
            '@action': "login", 
            '@appname': "app", 
            '@class': "login", 
            'nocookie': 1, 
            '@code': "101", 
            'psw': "12345", 
            '@relogin': "0", 
            '@username': "user123" 
        } 
}
```

I am getting 500 Error using the second payload. First payload works as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Show also how are you actually making the request, please.

Comment: You have two entirely different things here - one is a string, one is a dictionary.  Of course they work differently!

Comment: Please approve my answer in case it solved your issue. It's more important than upvoting it because it signals the right answer to other users looking for the solution to the same issue. Some answers may be helpful but don't exactly solve the OP issue. Those may be upvoted but not marked as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, you just need to create a JSON string from your structure using the [function `json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) first:

```
data = json.dumps(payload)
```

And then use the `data` variable instead of your original `payload`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `requests`:

> For example, the GitHub API v3 accepts JSON-Encoded POST/PATCH data:
>
> ```py
> >>> import json
>
> >>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
> >>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>
> >>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
> ```
>
> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be encoded automatically:
>
> ```
> >>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
> >>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>
> >>> r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
> ```

If you have a dictionary, and the API accepts JSON, you can just pass `json=payload`.